# How can I make a website “see me” as a totally new connection?

Tags: networking, router, ip, home-networking, identity-management

I'll summarize my problem as concisely as possible. I'm taking an online real estate course that requires, by law, that I spend a certain amount of time in each unit. For 2.5 months, the timer on the website worked perfectly, tracking the exact amount of time I'd been logged in to each unit. It worked perfectly when accessed from my home Mac (over WiFi), my iPhone (over LTE and home WiFi), my iPad (over home WiFi), and from my work PC (over ethernet). However, 5 days ago, the timer stopped counting, and no longer works from any device on any network that previously worked for me. I called Tech Support, but they were little help, suggesting I find a stronger internet connection.

Meanwhile, I've asked family and friends to log in, and they all see the timer working perfectly. Nothing has changed with my internet connections, at home or at work, and they're as strong as they've always been.

Because "new" devices seem to have no issues, my working theory is that my home network and/or devices have been "blacklisted" by their servers for some reason, possibly because of too many timed out sessions (I did tend to not log out).

So in short, to prove or disprove my theory, I'd like to be able gain a whole new identity, such that when I access the website, it believes I'm a new device on a new connection from which the website has never been accessed before. What would that entail? I have Verizon FIOS with their router using factory defaults. My home computer is an iMac running OS X El Capitan. I'm happy to mess with its settings.

I have 9 days remaining to complete 10 units worth of work, so I'm desperate to find a solution. Technical support is "working the issue", but I'm not confident they'll get to the bottom of it. If I don't finish the course material, they cannot give me an extension or refund me my money. Any support from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "If I don't finish the course material, they cannot give me an extension or refund me my money." I hope you paid with a credit card so you can do a chargeback. That said, I'd use a friend's computer or go to a library.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did pay with a credit card and I'm prepared to lean on that. I'm checking out my local library in the morning, which I presume will work. But a few tweaks to my computer and/or network at home would be worth it to finish it out from home.

Comment: Did you try different browsers?  If you normally use firefox try chrome.  If chrome try firefox.  Maybe even Internet explorer. (gasp)

Comment: Yes. I should have mentioned in my question that, once it stopped working, I attempted to access the site from my wife's Windows 10 laptop, using IE, which I had never done before. It still didn't work. So that particular data point leads me to believe that it's not the device, but the home wifi, that could be blacklisted. Seems like anything connected to it has this issue. Same thing at work.

Comment: If they were blacklisting IP addresses chances are you'd be unable to see the site at all. If you're technical, you could try checking your browser's JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: Yep, I am technical (webapp developer), and I did check my Chrome console for errors and found none. When I click the button on the site that tells me how much time I've "achieved" in the unit, it looks like it's making a REST call to get the info on-demand. This all leads me to believe that the time is tracked on the server, and not in the browser in any way. And that makes sense since it would be more secure. To your point about blacklisted IPs, I think it's possible that the "timer service" operates autonomously, with its own hypothetical blacklist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a "new connection", you can use a VPN service. If you only need something temporary, [Opera just announced](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2016/04/free-vpn-integrated-opera-for-windows-mac/) a free VPN service in their developer build. Plus you'll be using a new browser so if they had been blacklisting you based on IP *and* browser previously, you should pass that requirement now.

If this still fails, you could install Opera inside a virtual machine. This combination should make you appear 'completely new'. Again, if you only need something temporary, you can get a free (and legitimate!) [pre-prepared VM from Microsoft.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/)

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I'd need to do to my router? Or does the VPN take care of all those variables? I'm concerned that the connection on the way out will still be ultimately coming from the same IP, subnet, whatever.

Comment: Assuming your course is all done through a web browser and you're not using an application provided by the training provider, then you shouldn't need to change anything on your router. The traffic from the web browser is tunnelled through the VPN and exits from a different IP. That's the IP that your training providers website will see. Google has a service to test this by Googling: [what's my IP](https://www.google.com.au/#q=whats%20my%20ip).

Comment: It worked! Except I didn't need to use the Opera VPN. Simply accessing the site through a Modern.IE VM running Windows 7 and IE9, via my Mac, did the trick. Same internet connection, but different "computer". Definitely looks to me like they blacklisted my Mac. No idea why. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear, best of luck with the rest of your course!